# How do I add and use a plugin in Cordova?

Tags: cordova-plugins

Hy everyone.

I have an Android Phonegap/Cordova (3.5.0) project in Eclipse.
It works fine.

What I don't understand is: how do I install a plugin to use it as extension of PhoneGap basic APIs?

For example this: **http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/net.yoik.cordova.plugins.screenorientation**

I tried using **cordova plugin add net.yoik.cordova.plugins.screenorientation** from Windows command prompt, at various locations (**root** and **www/assets** directories) but I get an error (Windows prompt):
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

command is "cordova plugin add https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation" and it must be executed inside the Cordova app root directory.